# AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' error using select_by_index() to select an option from dropdown using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am a python newbie having an issue scraping the the text from a drop down table

here is where the issue is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.ehail.ca/quotes/?1590984761655")

desired_data =
Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/form[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[10]/select"))

desired_data.select_by_index(1)

print(desired_data.text))
```

and get the resulting error:

```
AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

I have also tried `print(desired_data.text)` but had no luck there.

Can I do this with selenium or will I need another library like beautiful soup?

Thank you for reading

edit1: I have filled in the required fields and still get same error. I am able to select the element but when try to print I get `<selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select object at 0x087810B8>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`.first_selected_option`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.first_selected_option) method first before use `.text` method.

Refers to the documentation:

> The first selected option in this select tag (or the currently selected option in a normal select)

```
desired_data.select_by_index(1)
print(desired_data.first_selected_option.text)
```

It will return the current selected option.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the correct behavior.

In your program, just after invoking `get(url)` as you are invoking the the `Select(webelement)` Class  on the desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) without filling out the previous mandatory fields, the `<option>` items doesn't gets populated/created:

[image: no_options]

Hence forcefully when you invoke `select_by_index(1)` method, which in turn internally calls `if opt.get_attribute("index") == match:` raises the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'
```

Implementation of [`select_by_index()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/select.html#Select.select_by_index):

```
def select_by_index(self, index):
    """Select the option at the given index. This is done by examing the "index" attribute of an
       element, and not merely by counting.

       :Args:
        - index - The option at this index will be selected

       throws NoSuchElementException If there is no option with specisied index in SELECT
       """
    match = str(index)
    for opt in self.options:
        if opt.get_attribute("index") == match:
            self._setSelected(opt)
            return
    raise NoSuchElementException("Could not locate element with index %d" % index)
```

---

### Solution

Filling up the previous mandatory fields, the `<option>` elements will get populated and the program execution will succeed.

Comment: I am still seeing that same error after filling the prior fields

Comment: Update the question with the additional observations.